# Find matches in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that contains phone numbers in different format:

```
$myArr[0][0] == '122-33-2222';
$myArr[1][0] == '(122) 433-5555';
$myArr[2][0] == '122 644.8888';
```

I need to check if another number is in that array. I assume I need to loop through array and strip all non-numeric values before I compare.

```
$findNumber = 122.433.5555;
$varPhone = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $findNumber);

foreach ($myArr AS $phone) {
   if (preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $phone) == $varPhone) {
      echo "found";
   } else {
      echo "not found";
   }
}
```

I think I'm close but it's not quite there. What am I missing?

Comment: First thing you're missing is quotes around the number in $findNumber! :) And a dollar sign before `phone` in your third preg_replace parameter

Comment: Sorry, typo -- was missing $.

Comment: Still missing the quotes though... Did you actually run this code snippet? :D

Comment: You better remove comma and dot, this will solve the problem, why did you add them to the pattern? use "/[^0-9]/" instead.

Comment: preg_replacing `(122) 433-5555` will lead to `1224335555`. So it will never be equal `122.433.5555`.

Comment: just make sure that you are breaking the loop after the if condition is true :)

Comment: Absolutely! Great point, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phone number is in the key `[0]` of each first-level array element, so you can't compare each instance of `$phone` directly. Also, I would replace all non-digit characters so that different notations still turn out as the same number.

```
<?php
// initialize array for the sake of this demo, to make this snippet work
$myArr = array(array(), array(), array());
$myArr[0][0] = '122-33-2222';
$myArr[1][0] = '(122) 433-5555';
$myArr[2][0] = '122 644.8888';

$findNumber = "122.433.5555";

function cleanNumber($in) {
  return preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $in);
}

foreach ($myArr AS $phone) {
   // the number is in the key [0] for each first-level array element
   if (cleanNumber($phone[0]) == cleanNumber($findNumber)) {
      echo "found<br>";
   } else {
      echo "not found<br>";
   }
}
```

this will output:

```
not found
found
not found
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your code, try the following:

```
$myArr[0][0] = '122-33-2222';
$myArr[1][0] = '(122) 433-5555';
$myArr[2][0] = '122 644.8888';

$findNumber = "122.433.5555";

$varPhone = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $findNumber);

foreach ($myArr AS $phone)
{
   $phone = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $phone);

   if ($phone[0] == $varPhone)
   {
        echo "found";
   }
   else
   {
      echo "not found";
   }
}
```

Remove the `,` and `.` from the regex and as `$phone` is an array, treat it as such.

Output:

```
not foundfoundnot found
```

Comment: You forgot your var_dump in there! :)

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following snippet that might work

```
<?php
$myArr[0] = '122-33-2222';
$myArr[1] = '(122) 433-5555';
$myArr[2]    = '122 644.8888';

$findNumber = "122.433.5555";
$varPhone = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $findNumber);
$flag = false;
foreach ($myArr AS $phone) {
   if (preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $phone) == $varPhone) {
      $flag = true;
      break;

   } 
}

if($flag)
    echo "found";
else
    echo "not found";

?>
```

Changes:-
$myArr should be 1d array and not 2d array,

== is comparison operator, assigning operator should be use instead.

in preg_replace even dots should be replaced with empty

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of your code:

```
$myArr[0][0] = '122-33-2222';
$myArr[1][0] = '(122) 433-5555';
$myArr[2][0] = '122 644.8888';

$findNumber = '122.433.5555';
$normalize = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $findNumber);

$found = false;
foreach ($myArr AS $phone) {
  if ($normalize == preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $phone[0])) {
    $found = true;
    break;
  }
}

echo $found;
```

An even better approach would be using `array_filter`

```
$myArr[0][0] = '122-33-2222';
$myArr[1][0] = '(122) 433-5555';
$myArr[2][0] = '122 644.8888';

$findNumber = '122.433.5555';
$normalize = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $findNumber);

$filtered =array_filter($myArr, function ($phone) use ($normalize) {
  return preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $phone[0]) == $normalize;
});

var_dump($filtered);
echo sizeof($filtered);
```